# Malloc error in excel called .exe library

Tags: c, excel, vba, malloc

I'm using office 365 in 64 bit, with Windows 10 OS.

I compile my .exe file with Visual Studio 2017 Community.

Each time I met `malloc()` function, it report a violation of memory access.

It is nearly impossible for me to stop using `malloc` since there are some data base API also used `malloc`.

The following are codes from Excel (VBA):

```vb
Option Explicit
Public Declare PtrSafe Function ExcelCalc Lib "E:\AEONLIFE\CalcMProj\ActThread2\x64\Debug\ActThread2.exe" ( _
                ByVal PlanCode As String, _
                ByVal chnl As Long, _
                ByVal sensi As Long, _
                ByRef a As Double, _
                ByRef b As Double) As Long

Dim a(0 To 1273) As Double
Dim b(0 To 1273) As Double


Sub test()
    Dim c As Long
    Dim PlanCode As String


    c = ExcelCalc("502001", 1, 0, a(1), b(1))
End Sub
```

The following is C code:

```
extern __declspec(dllexport) int WINAPI ExcelCalc(char *PlanCode, int chnl, int scen, double *a, double *b)
{
#pragma region 初始化
    //**********  本地变量  **********
    double     mfac = (double)1 / (double)YEARSTEP;
    char       TempPID[PlanIDLEN];
    int        Ind, PlanCodeInt;
    DB         dbconn;
    pfdrv      ProfDrv;
    tData      Data;
    temp       Temp;
    //********** 申请堆空间 **********
    cashflow  *CashFlow     = malloc(sizeof(cashflow));
    sensi     *Sensi        = malloc(sizeof(sensi));
    calcconst *CalcConst    = malloc(sizeof(calcconst)*MAXCHNL);
    cf_calc   *CF_Calc_Base = malloc(sizeof(cf_calc));
    rate_calc *RateCalc     = malloc(sizeof(rate_calc));
    decrate   *DecRate      = malloc(MAXCHNL * sizeof(decrate));
    //********** 链接数据库 **********
    if (dbconnect(&dbconn) == FAIL) { return 0; };
#pragma endregion
    strcpy_s(&TempPID[0], sizeof(TempPID), PlanCode);
    TempPID[4]  = 0;
    PlanCodeInt = atoi(&TempPID[0]);

    LoadAsump(PlanCode, &dbconn, DecRate, CashFlow, Sensi, CalcConst, &ProfDrv, mfac);
    Ind = LoadTemp(&Data, &Temp, DecRate, &CashFlow->GCV[0], &CashFlow->CFOutgo[chnl], mfac);

    Calc_CashFlow(&Temp, CF_Calc_Base, &CashFlow->CFOutgo[chnl], &CalcConst[chnl], PlanCodeInt, mfac);
    CalcDec(&Temp, &DecRate[chnl], RateCalc, &Sensi->SensiRT[scen][0], &CalcConst[chnl], mfac);


#pragma region 计算后处理
    //********** 释放堆空间 **********
    free(DecRate);
    free(CashFlow);
    free(Sensi);
    free(CalcConst);
    //**********  断开链接  **********
    dbcleares(&dbconn);
    PQfinish(dbconn.conn);
#pragma endregion

    a[0] = 1;
    a[1] = 3.5;
    b[0] = 1;
    b[1] = 7;
    return 1;
}
```

Little bit complicated but the error appears in line 12, the first malloc(), as the following picture:

[image]

It's Chinese and says memory access violation in address 0x181FC1A.

I did assembly debugging, it seems that I didn't load the library that containing malloc. I'll try to load the relating library and try again.

Thanks!!

Comment: Please post your code and the output you receive when running the code.

Comment: What is the actual error message?  did your code call `perror()` when malloc failed, so you/we have the text reason the system thinks the error occurred?

Comment: please post a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem

Comment: There is near zero context in this question whatsoever. For all we know you're writing a stand-alone exe and experiencing problems doing so, while concurrently toting useless information about your installed OS and office suite. Please, *please*, think long and hard about what your given scenario is, what the *specific* problem you're trying to solve is, and how you're trying to solve it. Provide **all** required information for us to provide assistance. Right now all we know is somehow, some way, you're calling `malloc` and experiencing some error.

Comment: Codes and error screen shoot attached, as I said it just reported an memory access error. The error was invoked at the first malloc function call.

Comment: I think its because the C library is not loaded, since the process is started from Excel. But I don't know the way of loading library and allocate them to the correct address.

Comment: Updated, when compile with dll format, the problem gone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is, the PE was compiled as .exe file.

When calling from Excel process, the .exe file only provide the function, but will not loading related library and dependencies.

To fix it, the .dll format need to be applied, thus the Windows PE loader will load the correct dependencies into the correct address.